# Find and replace in all rows and all columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of projects which from 1 to 90. All the formulas in the same row for each project up to column 200 should contain formula linking to the correct project number. For example:

A1:

```
Project 1
```

B1:

```
=IFERROR('C:\Users\z003th4b.AD009\Desktop\Gross margin bridges\Projects\[Project (1).xlsm]Nov 17'!$D$3;" ")
```

C1:

```
=IFERROR('C:\Users\z003th4b.AD009\Desktop\Gross margin bridges\Projects\[Project (1).xlsm]File_Setup'!$D$17;" ")`
```

A2:

```
Project 2
```

B2:

```
=IFERROR('C:\Users\z003th4b.AD009\Desktop\Gross margin bridges\Projects\[Project (2).xlsm]Nov 17'!$D$3;" ")
```

C2:

```
=IFERROR('C:\Users\z003th4b.AD009\Desktop\Gross margin bridges\Projects\[Project (2).xlsm]File_Setup'!$D$17;" ")
```

and so on up to 90 projects.

Currently I am using

```
Sub macro ()
  ActiveCell.Range("A31:BH90").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="Project (1)", Replacement:="Project (2)", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(62, 0).Range("A31:BH90").Select

end sub
```

and it doesn't seem to work. I am absolutely new to VBA so I will appreciate any help. Thank!

Comment: Your range starts at row 31 so if you have data in A1, this macro will miss it.

Comment: I need to code to start considering from A31 since all projects before that are ok. that should not be a problem for the VBA to run I guess..

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work` is not a very useful description of any kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Macro ()
  ActiveCell.Range("A1:BH90").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="Project (1)", Replacement:="Project (2)", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(62, 0).Range("A1:BH90").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you that seem to work, but how can I make it that all Project 1s that I have copied up to row 90 turn into following numbers Project 1 project 2 and so on ..

Comment: You need to assign a variable. @Ralph answer can provide you some hints.